# Read 3D array (images) with csv.reader

Tags: python, csv

As part of an online course, I have to create a function that reads a large set of image data using csv (not allowed to use pandas) and outputs the images and their labels in the correct format, as numpy array floats.

I will try to make a short example here:

```
> raw_data = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>            L1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
>            L2,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3
>            .....................
>            L20 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
> 
>  output1 = [L1, L2 .... L20] 
>  output2 = [1.0,2.0,3.0         (for a single row)
>            4.0,5.0,6.0
>            7.0,8.0,9.0] 
>  output1.shape = 20 
>  output2.shape= 20, 3, 3
```

First row should be ignored (it is the column names). 
Each row consists of 10 values, representing the 9 pixels of the given image, + the first column of each row which is the label for the respective image. 
After I read the images and the labels, I have to convert them to float values and reshape each 9 pixel row into a 3x3 matrix.

For example if the original data set has 20 rows (minus the first row), the two outputs of the function should have a shape of (20, 3, 3) and (20) - i.e. 20 3x3 images, and an array of 20 labels.

I never used the csv reader and with open before, so I'm struggling. 
This is what I have so far (this is the original code for the original data set, which is much larger than the example I gave).

> 

```
with open(filename) as file:
         file = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')   
         for row in file:
             images = row[1:785]
             labels = row[0]
         labels = np.array(labels).astype('float')
         images = np.array(images).astype('float')
         images = np.array(np.split(images, 28))  
         print('label:', labels.shape)
         print('image:', images.shape)
return images, labels
```

In the end, the shapes I am getting are 
(3,3) for the images - hence only the first row has been read; 
() for the labels - hence, empty.

When I tried to put the array conversion inside the for loop, it refuses to convert the str into float, I get an error.

> Value error: Can not convert string to float

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. I also think you should reduce the size of the images — i.e. a lot fewer pixels per row — and then provide sample input and desired output.

Comment: The data is coming from the Jupyter Notebook of the course, but I can try to illustrate what I want to do :)

Comment: That helps a little, although I was hoping you could just cut and paste a small sample of the real data — the reason being so I would have something to use to reproduce the error and test solutions with. Since you appear to be wanting to interpret the labels as float values, I assume they don't actually have alphanumeric values like "L3", correct?